# Runtime Error in Leetcode problem 19 -- remove nth node from end of list

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am working on LeetCode problem [19. Remove Nth Node From End of List](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/submissions/):

> Given the `head` of a linked list, remove the nth node from the end of the list and return its head.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1,2,3,4,5], n = 2
> Output: [1,2,3,5]
> ```
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - The number of nodes in the list is `sz`.
> - `1 <= sz <= 30`
> - `0 <= Node.val <= 100`
> - `1 <= n <= sz`

This is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* head, int n) {
        ListNode *p=head,*q=head,*t=NULL;
        long long  c=0;
        while(p!=0){
            c++;
            p=p->next;
        }
        c=c-n;
        while(q!=NULL && c>0){
            t=q;
            q=q->next;
            c--;
        }
        t->next=q->next;
        delete q;
        return head;
    }
};
```

I get this error when one of the test cases is run:

```
Line 26: Char 12: runtime error: 
         member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:35:12
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error, because according to what I think, both `t` and `q` are not `NULL` here at the moment. So, I shouldn't have gotten this error.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't write alphabet soup. Give things descriptive names.

Comment: Consider using a stack. As you iterate through the list, add a pointer to each item to the stack. Then all you need to do is pop `n` times to find the node you need to remove. Also worth making sure that some jerk doesn't give a `n` larger than the list.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and feed in the input set that causes failure. Then step until you see something you don't expect.

Comment: Also a good idea to test your code with the same sanitizers turned on. That means you need a compiler with sanitizers enabled and on Windows this usually means clang.

Comment: What happens when you try and remove the 0th from the end? https://godbolt.org/z/MEx7YrhMG

Comment: *"according to what I think, both t and q are not NULL here at the moment"* -- at which moment? Which line? (The error message says line 26, but why should each person reading the question have to count lines, when you could do it once for everyone? Just put in a comment `// This is line 26` and refer to that comment when you say "here".) Why do you believe both `t` and `q` are not null? (Spell it out for us even if you think it is obvious.)

Answer (score 0):

> according to what I think, both t and q are not NULL

...not when `n` is equal to the size of the list, in which case `c` will be 0 after `c=c-n` is executed. In that case the second loop will make no iterations, leaving `t` equal to `NULL` (BTW, you should really be using `nullptr` in C++).

In that boundary case, you need to remove the first node, and return a different `head` pointer.

So replace:

```
        t->next=q->next;
```

with

```
        if (t == nullptr) {
            head = q->next;
        } else {
            t->next = q->next;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign `q = head` and then run this loop.

```
while(q!=NULL && c>0){
            t=q;
            q=q->next;
            c--;
}
```

But what happens if `head` is `nullptr`? Then `t` is still `nullptr`.

Then it makes this line crash.

```
t->next=q->next;
```

So, you can check `head` is not `nullptr` at the beginning, OR you can check `t` is not nullptr before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Leetcode will teach you how to solve problems but it will not teach you good C++. C++ comes with a lot of build in datastructures and algorithms that should be used instead of the coding style shown on leetcode.
Compare this code with the typical examples on leetcode and you might get a feel for that difference. (including giving variables readable names and writing small functions to increase readability)

E.g. Use C++'s std::list instead of writing your own

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

void erase_pos_from_last(std::list<int>& list, std::size_t pos)
{
    // never trust your input!
    if (pos >= list.size())
    {
        return; // do nothing
        // or throw std::invalid_argument("pos cannot be larger then the size of your list");
    }

    auto last = list.size() - 1;
    auto it = list.begin();
    std::advance(it, last - pos);
    list.erase(it);
}


int main()
{
    std::list<int> values{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
    erase_pos_from_last(values,6ul);
    

    for (const auto& value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```